# DB2 returning keys in insert not working

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

I'm having a problem while returning generated keys when insert a row with jdbc in a DB2 database (version 10.1). I tried several ways to do it, but no one works fine.

Method 1:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

When executing this line, I get this exception:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.61.75

Method 2:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, pkMapper.getPkFieldNames());
List<Object> params = getInsertParams(object, pkMapper);
for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
    Object param = params.get(i);
    stmt.setObject(i+1, param);
}
```

`pkMapper.getPkFieldNames()` returns an array of string with PK column names. When executing `stmt.setObject(i+1, param);` I get an exception like this:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.61.75

Method 3:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
```

With this form, insert is executed fine, but no keys are returned with `stmt.getGeneratedKeys();`

Has anyone any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your database is v. 10.1? According to [this list](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) the JDBC driver version 3.61.75 belongs to v9.7 fix pack 3a. If your database _is_ 10.1, try updating you JDBC driver to a matching version.

Comment: What platform is your DB2 database running on?  The message looks like it's from DB2 on z/OS.

Comment: Yes, it is a  DB2 on z/OS. I cant change jdbc driver...